# Pick a random 3D point on a tilted circle

Tags: circles, rotations, sampling

I know how to pick a random point [on a circle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CirclePointPicking.html) or [on a sphere](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpherePointPicking.html), but how could I pick a random point on a *tilted* unit circle?

By *tilted*, I mean that the circle is not in a *xy*, *xz* or *yz* plane. Instead, let $\vec u$ be the vector normal to the circle's plane.

One obvious solution would be to pick a random point on the *xy* unit circle, then apply a rotation matrix that would transform $\vec z$ to $\vec u$. However, this does not work because some pesky divisions by zero occur when $\vec u=\vec z$. When trying to achieve this numerically, machine precision errors also occurs when $\vec u\sim\vec z$. I could certainly separate the solution in two cases by rotating the system by $\pi/2$ when needed, but that is not practical.

Is there an elegant solution that works for any $\vec u$?

Comment: "but that is not practical" Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to generate two unit vectors in the plane of the tilted circle. Since you already have the normal $\vec{u}=(u_x,u_y,u_z)$ you could use for instance $\vec{v} = (-u_y,u_x,0)$ and the other $\vec{w}=\vec{u} \times \vec{v} = (-u_x u_z,-u_y u_z,u_x^2+u_y^2)$ and normalise them.

Then use your favourite method to generate a point $(x,y)$ on the unit-circle and transform this to a point on the tilted circle $x \hat{u} + y \hat{v}$.

Adding the comment of Robert Israel. In the case that numerical issues would arise caused by $u_x,u_y$ being close to zero you can take a $\vec{v}=(u_z,0,-u_x)$ or $(0,u_z,-u_y)$ as an alternative. This might occur/become important if you have to generate many such points on different randomly tilted circles.

Outlined above is one of the standard ways of solving the problem, where in a computer code for particular problems that require consistent high numerical accuracy different cases will have to be considered.

Comment: If both $u_x$ and $u_y$ happen to be $0$ (or very close), you'll want to make a different choice, e.g. $(-u_z, 0, u_x)$.

Comment: Following @Robert's comment, the proposed solution requires a special case, so it does not work for me. But thanks for the suggestion

Comment: There is no  continuous mapping that takes a unit vector $\vec{u}$ to another unit vector orthogonal to it: a consequence of the "hairy billiard ball" theorem.  So inevitably there will be "cases".